# Is $\Bbb R$ closed under subtraction?

Tags: linear-algebra

It is easy to see that:
$∀(x,y)∈ \Bbb R$
$(x+y) ∈ \Bbb R$
But for example $(-7)-(-10)≠(-10)-(-7)$
so if I understand correctly $\Bbb R$
is not closed under subtraction?

Comment: What is your definition of "closed under substraction"?

Comment: but both numers are reals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have shown is that subtraction is not commutative. Since $(\mathbb R,+)$ is an abelian group, it must be closed under subtraction when $a-b$ is defined as $a+(-b)$.

Comment: But if  $(R,+)$ is an abelian group,a+(-b)=(-b)+a and in the example I wrote it does not work

Comment: @NFLX Both sides are still in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Just to be sure I understood,(R,+) is abelian group (and therefore a+b=b+a) and (R,-) not abelian group,but both (R,+) and (R,-) Is closed under subtraction because a+b or a-b is in R?

Comment: @NFLX Yes. ${}{}{}$

Comment: ok,thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You are conflating commutativity and closure.

To assert closure, you'd need to assess

> Is  $(-7)-(-10)\in\Bbb{R}?$

Which is true. However, you've already pointed out that $a-b \ne b-a.$